# HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.getNetworkTimeout()I)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

i,m creating a simple maven project with spring boot and hibernate and i want to create my table in mysqlDB with hibernate.when i run my spring application its not creating my table and i have no error but title massage will appear and i think this is the cause of my problem

```
`2019-05-31 14:02:54.781  INFO 25517 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.getNetworkTimeout()I)`
```

pom.xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>Example</groupId>
<artifactId>Example</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### `

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.password=dani861
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.jooq.sql-dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

RUN:

```
2019-05-31 14:35:54.116  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.configuration.SpringConfiguration    : Starting SpringConfiguration on Daniyal with PID 26667 (/home/daniyal/IdeaProjects/Example/target/classes started by daniyal in /home/daniyal/IdeaProjects/Example)
2019-05-31 14:35:54.119  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.configuration.SpringConfiguration    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-31 14:35:54.164  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-05-31 14:35:54.165  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-05-31 14:35:54.848  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-05-31 14:35:54.869  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2019-05-31 14:35:55.259  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4830e052] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-05-31 14:35:55.598  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-05-31 14:35:55.631  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-05-31 14:35:55.631  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
2019-05-31 14:35:55.715  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-05-31 14:35:55.715  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1550 ms
2019-05-31 14:35:55.868  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-05-31 14:35:56.075  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.getNetworkTimeout()I)
2019-05-31 14:35:56.077  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-05-31 14:35:56.117  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2019-05-31 14:35:56.163  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
2019-05-31 14:35:56.164  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/3306/test, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.show_sql=true, jdbc.user=root, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop, jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver, jdbc.pass=dani861}
2019-05-31 14:35:56.192  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2019-05-31 14:35:56.282  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-05-31 14:35:56.306  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
2019-05-31 14:35:56.454  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@cf13b9f'
2019-05-31 14:35:56.456  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-05-31 14:35:56.473  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-05-31 14:35:56.680  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-05-31 14:35:56.717  WARN 26667 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-05-31 14:35:56.957  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-05-31 14:35:56.960  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.configuration.SpringConfiguration    : Started SpringConfiguration in 3.121 seconds (JVM running for 3.414)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your log, it seems to me that hibernate is using properties from hibernate.properties

```
2019-05-31 14:35:56.164  INFO 26667 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/3306/test, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.show_sql=true, jdbc.user=root, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop, jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver, jdbc.pass=dani861}
```

This line is showing that it's trying to use the H2 Database as driver and dialect.

In your pom.xml, you are declaring all de dependencies to spring data jpa e hibernate but using spring boot it makes more sense if you use the spring-boot-starter-jpa dependency. It provides auto-configuration classes to help you.

Take a look at this guide: [Link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using :

pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

yaml config

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

log :

```
 com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
 com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
```